# Связь между программами python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть две программы написанные на python. Как из первой программы направить запрос во вторую?

То есть условно говоря первая программа отправляет текст "Hello, world!", а вторая его получает и выводит на экран

**UPD 1:** Я не имею в виду работу с библиотекой socket и ей подобными

**UPD 2:** Обе программы запускаются на одном компьютере

**UPD 3:** Я не имею ввиду работу с импортами

Comment: Зависит от той программы, которая должна принять информацию. В ней должен быть явно написан код который откуда то получает данные. И если там такое предусмотрено, то надо посмотреть как именно она готова получать данные.  Ответ на ваш вопрос невозможен без просмотра кода программ

Comment: В любом уважающем себя интерпретаторе команд есть возможность перенаправить вывод одной программы в ввод другой программы `python программа1.py | python программа2.py`

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: @andreymal, да, но как это сделать? как написать первую и вторую программы чтобы они могли 'общаться' между собой

Comment: вот вам две программы, одна передаёт другой строку `12`, вторая преобразует строку в число, прибавляет единицу, и печатает результат: `$ python3 -c 'print(12)' | python3 -c 'x=int(input());print(x+1)'`. но это одностороннее общение. про двустороннее — ссылку на википедию привёл Mike.

Answer (score 2):

Под вопросом "Как сделать запрос во вторую программу?" я наверное понял, как вам из одной программы достать переменную/вызвать функцию из другой программы.

Я пишу код для примера, а автор вопроса уже сам адаптирует его под себя:

```
#main1.py

def func():
    int1 = 10
    print(int1)
```

```
#main2.py
from main1 import func
func()
```

Есть несколько примечаний:

1. Оба .py файла должны быть в одной папке (если они в разных папках, то нужно импортировать уже из папки так):

```
#C:\Users\[имя пользователя]\Dekstop\testfolder\main1.py
def func():
    int1 = 10
    print(int1)
```

```
#C:\Users\[имя пользователя]\Desktop\main2.py

from testfolder.main1 import func
func()
```

2. Нельзя делать так:

```
#main1.py
from main2 import func2
def func1():
    int1 = 10
    print(int1)
```

```
#main2.py
from main1 import func1
def func2():
   int2 = 20
   print(int2)
```

Если так сделать, то смотря с какого файла ты запустишь программу вылезет такая ошибка:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'main1' from partially initialized module 'main2' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

3. Если Вы собрались компилировать программу через pyinstaller в один .exe файл, то не забудьте прописать это:

```
pyinstaller --onefile main1.py -p main2.py
```

Первое название файла после `--onefile` будет выступать некой "точкой запуска", то есть файл `main1.py` будет являться основной программой. Имейте это в виду.

**Надеюсь, автор получил тот ответ, который хотел.**

Comment: нет, я не имел ввиду импорты, мне нужно чтобы программы были независимы от импортов

Comment: @MenlisSmith к сожалению я не знаю, как можно иначе как-то провести связь между обоими программами не используя импорты, если уж существует способ "связать" между собой два  питоновских файла с кодом не используя импорты, то зачем вам это нужно?